# Possible side effects of changing shell from zsh to bash

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

My web server was tampered by someone who was using zsh shell. I feel more comfortable using bash shell, as that's the defaults that come with Ubuntu and OS X (the two main operating systems I use). But this questions is focused on Ubuntu server.

I have 4 websites running on this web server, I use byobu, I use tmux, I use ruby/ruby on rails, node.js, Apache, a few daemons. If I switch the current root shell from zsh to bash, could there be any negative side effects that might result from this switch? For example, will processes be killed because their parent process (the shell) has been switched?

Comment: Are you asking about the consequences of the change (which are none, I'm using zsh right now and can switch to bash whenever I like) or are you asking about how to effectively change the shell?

Comment: @Braiam I am nervous about the consequences of the change. If there are no consequences, then I will change. I was just thinking that the shell was a parent process to some of these daemons like apache, and if I was to switch out of it, that it would kill the apache process. But I guess I am wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Changing your shell, via `sudo chsh --shell=/bin/bash $USER` will change the shell field in `/etc/passwd`. This value is only consulted at login time, when the system has no idea of which shell to use for you.

Running processes, whether started by `zsh`, `bash` `apache` or `evil_overlord's_program` won't be affected

Comment: Isn't the shell the parent process of other processes running in it, or just the controlling terminal (and not the shell) would be considered the parent process?

Comment: The `login` program runs in a process, like everything. When it lets you in, it creates another process with your UID, etc, and runs /bin/bash (from /etc/passwd). The bash shell reads from STDIN (set up by `login`), and will fork/exec non-builtin commands, wait for them to terminate, and loop for more commands. The idea of "controlling terminal" is not useful in Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 37):

Answer from the Stack Overflow ([switching from zsh to bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341271/switching-from-zsh-to-bash-on-osx-and-back-again)):

> You can just use exec to replace your current shell with a new shell:
>
> Switch to bash:
>
> ```
> exec bash
> ```
>
> Switch to zsh:
>
> ```
> exec zsh
> ```
>
> This won't affect new terminal windows or anything, but it's
>   convenient.

Comment: did not work. still : echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/zsh

Comment: @ses `$SHELL` gives you the **default login** shell. `$0` gives you the **current** shell (the name of the running process) and `$$` is the process ID (PID) of the script itself. Try [`ps $$
`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96307/209677) or [`echo $0`](https://askubuntu.com/a/590902/349837)

Answer (score 9):

Open your terminal and use the following command:

```
chsh -s $(which bash)
```

Comment: I assume this is the equivalent of chsh -s /bin/bash

Comment: `which bash` would give the absolute path of `bash`, so it would be the same if `/bin/bash` is where `bash` was located.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS Catalina

1. Change to zsh:

   ```
   chsh -s /bin/zsh
   ```
2. Change to bash:

   ```
   chsh -s /bin/bash
   ```