# How do I check which shell I am using?

Tags: command-line

I read that terminal is nothing but shell, and Unix provides different flavors of shells:

- Bourne shell (sh)
- C shell (csh)
- TC shell (tcsh)
- Korn shell (ksh)
- Bourne Again shell (bash)

#### Questions:

- When I open a terminal window, which shell is opened by default?
- How do I check how many shells are installed?
- How do I change the shell used from my account?

Comment: [How to determine the current shell I'm working on?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3327013/4023950) on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @KasiyA This is also related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/87853/what-is-default-shell-for-terminal

Comment: Please note that terminal is interface to the shell (which at one point used to be actually physical interface), and shell is  not terminal - it is a command  interpreter. See also https://askubuntu.com/a/640105/295286

Answer (score 751, accepted):

You can type the following command in your terminal to see which shell you are using:

```
echo $0
```

The result will look something similar to the below if you are using the *bash* (**Bourne Again Shell**) terminal:

```
-bash
```

Comment: is `0` an environment variable?

Comment: @Mi_Onim $0 is the name of the running process. If you use it inside of a shell then it will return the name of the shell. If you use it inside of a script, it will be the name of the script.

Comment: **NOTE**: this won't work for interactive  `csh`. `% echo $0
No file for $0.` , but it does work for `tcsh`

Comment: Doesn't work if when one is symlink. Like `bash` as `sh`

Comment: @Serg is there a way to find `csh` as well? or is that by design?

Comment: @Anwar makes a good point, after you get the shell name from `echo $0`, ``ls -l `which <name>` `` to see if it is symlinked to another shell binary.

Comment: Does not work for `su - user`

Comment: This is a bad solution.  The name of a program can be changed in so many ways.

Comment: does not work for fish shell

Comment: Accessed in a shell function named `myfunc`, `$0` is `bash` for bash, but `myfunc` for zsh.

Comment: This is a brittle solution which will break in sourced scripts.

Comment: @AlexanderRevo well I guess it’s a good thing then that the question wasn’t centered around “sourced” scripts ;)

Comment: @kingmilo while you are technically not wrong, a solution that only works in certain scenarios would benefit from a disclaimer.

Comment: @AlexanderRevo I understand your point, but the user asking the question was the same user who accepted my answer, I don’t have control over that. If the user is satisfied with an answer then the entire purpose of this forum has been achieved. If you decide to mark the answer down, that’s fine, and encouraged if you don’t agree, I’m not disputing that. I am disputing your comment though. You have asked that I add a disclaimer to my answer, yet you have submitted a comment which doesn’t fit the context of the question/answer at all. I hope you manage to see the irony in this all =]

Comment: @masukomi for fish shell, check the next answer down, which recommends `echo $SHELL` or checking PIDs

Comment: This doesn't work with `zsh` during the execution of a `source` command. To confirm this, try creating the file `foo.sh` with the following content `echo $0` and then create `main.sh` with the following content `echo $0 && source ./foo.sh` and you will see  that the output of executing `zsh main.sh` is `zsh.sh\n./foo.sh`. That's why I state that `$0` doesn't work with `zsh`.

Comment: @mblakesley that does not work for non POSIX shells like fish - and echo $SHELL bears no connection with the actual shell you are running

Comment: Worth noting if you have more than one Bash installed (which may be common e.g. on macOS which ships with outdated Bash by default), then this approach does not show you which one you are running - if you need that, I have just added an answer which does.

Comment: it is show me this on ArchLinux  /usr/bin/zsh

Answer (score 214):

To find the shell you have on the default environment you can check the value of the `SHELL` environment variable:

```
echo $SHELL
```

To find the current shell instance, look for the process (shell) having the PID of the current shell instance.

To find the PID of the current instance of shell:

```
echo "$$"
```

Now to find the process having the PID:

```
ps -p <PID>
```

Putting it together:

```
ps -p "$$"
```

Comment: $SHELL is the default shell for the system (or user), which is usually (but not necessarily) the shell that is actually being used at any given moment.

Comment: @kingmilo: Right you are, answer modified.

Comment: I found this pretty useful when switching to a user through 'su - <username>', e.g. for setting up postgres, jenkins, ...

Comment: `echo $SHELL` gave me `/bin/csh` and `ps -p $$` gave me `22673 pts/1    00:00:00 bash`.  Kingmilo explained (above) why they are not the same.

Comment: @18446744073709551615 I have not said either that they are the same. Please read the answer carefully again; note the _default_ and _current_ wordings.

Comment: @heemayl I already did. Of course when the code gives unexpected results, one reads the text near it. It is logical.

Comment: for a shell script to start a new session

Comment: To grab ONLY the shell name for the current shell in a way portable between gnu & bsd ps versions, this works well: `ps -cp "$$" -o command=""`

Comment: thank you @James Tomasino that worked the best!

Comment: "$$" is not the pid in fish shell "$fish_pid" is. Fish will let you know this but if you don't know you're in fish it's an annoying error that makes this particular method unreliable for determining your shell.

Comment: Funny, I did `kill $(echo "$$")` and my shell is still running

Comment: doing a "./test.sh" on the command line will resolve to reporting "test.sh" as the invoked command. - in this case the solution is not really working.

Comment: @masukomi mentions that fish will let you know "$$" is not the pid; but in my version of fish it says `fish: $$ is not the pid. In fish, please use %self.` But at least at that point, I know I'm using a fish shell, not bash, as `echo $SHELL` would lead me to believe.

Comment: does not work with fish shell

Comment: When I run `ps -cp "$$" -o command=""` as a shell command from the GHCI REPL, I get `ps` as the output instead of the shell it uses.

Answer (score 65):

`$SHELL` gives you the default shell.
`$0` gives you the current shell.

For example: I have bash as my default shell, which I use for my Terminal App. But for my iTerm2 app, I use the command as the window opens: `/bin/ksh`.

So my 
`$0` gives me `/bin/ksh` on iTerm2.
`$SHELL` gives me `/bin/bash` on iTerm2.
`$0`,`$SHELL` gives me `/bin/bash` on Terminal

Comment: This is a nice disambiguation of the other top-voted answers. Thank you.

Comment: For me, I have zsh installed and it's the current default, to change to bash, all I have to do type `bash` in the terminal. To switch back to zsh, type `zsh`

Comment: You don't want to keep going back and forth that way because you stack up shell within shell within shell, and a fresh context within each. In general it's best to type ctrl-d or exit to return to the previous shell.

Comment: Best answer, should be chosen as answer. Agree to yousuf Azad on changing shell, but also agree to stacking issue indicated by Phill Apley. My default is also `zsh`, but to switch I type `bash`, and to return back I can simply do `exit` or ctrl + D

Answer (score 24):

The other answers tend to be using shell specific features, but we are trying to discover which shell we are using, so they assume the answer to the problem. For example none of the answers will work on fish.

```
sh -c 'ps -p $$ -o ppid=' | xargs ps -o comm= -p
```

Instead use the $$ syntax in an invocation of sh, but then we are looking for the PPID not the PID. Use the PPID to find the cmd.

```
sh -c 'ps -p $$ -o ppid=' | xargs -I'{}' readlink -f '/proc/{}/exe'
```

Thanks for improvement @muru

Comment: You ca use `ppid=`/`cmd=`to omit the headers (and so the `tail -1`s), and consider looking at `/proc/.../exe` to see what file is being run (since the `cmd` output can be manipulated by whatever ran the shell).

Comment: Apparently this does not work in busybox, due to non posix compliance: ref: https://github.com/broadinstitute/cromwell/pull/3561#pullrequestreview-116186537

Comment: What does your first code block exemplify?

Comment: this solution solves the problem of assuming the shell but introduces the problem of assuming the OS. The BSD version of readlink shipped with macOS (and presumably other BSD Distros) uses -f to specify "format" which is a printf style string that must start and end with % and has a variety of templating options.

Comment: Great answer, @EvanBenn, thanks!  Here is a tiny modification to allow it to work with shells like `BusyBox`, where the `-p` arg to `ps` isn't supported, and where there aren't a whole lot of other utilities like `cut` to help. Code: `set -- $(ps -o pid,ppid | grep -E "^ *$$"); readlink -f "/proc/${2}/exe"`.  I'm using your method to determine the shells used on a bunch of "free online Linux shell" websites, and it's great!

Comment: @Sean add it in an edit if you like!

Comment: I tried running @Sean's command, and fish complained at me, for multiple reasons. Granted I'm not running BusyBox, but at least it complained in a way that I know I'm running fish. The second command in the original answer worked for me, on an Ubuntu-based system.

Comment: @EvanBenn, @hlongmore : If you want to support odd shells like `fish` and `csh` and you still want to get the parent shell's executable path (the PPID rather than the PID), the following will work: `test ! -z "$shell" && set empty && set pid="$$$empty" || test ! -z "$fish_pid" && set pid "$fish_pid" || export pid="$$$empty"; ps -o pid,ppid | grep -E "^ *$pid" | grep -o '[^ ]*$' | xargs -I ppid readlink -f "/proc/ppid/exe" | cat`

Comment: If you prefer to get the executable path of the _current_ shell, just change it to: `test ! -z "$shell" && set empty && set pid="$$$empty" || test ! -z "$fish_pid" && set pid "$fish_pid" || export pid="$$$empty"; readlink -f "/proc/$pid/exe" | cat`

Answer (score 14):

The original post asked three questions. The answers given do cover the first question, "When I open a terminal window, which shell is opened by default?" They also answer a question which was NOT asked, namely "How can I find out which shell is currently running in the terminal?" However, as far as I can see nobody has answered either the second or third questions originally asked, namely "How do I check how many shells are installed?" and "How do I change the shell used from my account?"

- To answer "How do I check how many shells are installed?" the following command will list all the available shells:

  ```
  cat /etc/shells
  ```

  For example, on a default installation of Ubuntu 18.10 this gives:

  ```
  # /etc/shells: valid login shells
  /bin/sh
  /bin/dash 
  /bin/bash
  /bin/rbash
  ```

  However, by default sh is a symbolic link to dash, while rbash links to bash with the option -r ("restricted bash") so there are actually only two shells, not four as the above list suggests. The following command will show you whether any of the listed shells are in fact symbolic links, and if so where they link to:
  ls -l /bin
- Now for the question "How do I change the shell used from my account?" Assuming this means "How do I permanently change the default shell that a terminal will use", there is an answer [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ChangingShells#Changing_your_login_shell_which_is_permanent).

Answer (score 13):

To know which is the default shell for your user, you can run:

```bsh
echo "$SHELL"
```

For example if you're using Bash you should get the following output:

```
/bin/bash
```

If you didn't change any configuration it should be Bash since Bash it's the default shell on Ubuntu.

Comment: /bin/sh is the Shell Command Language and not the Bourne Shell, please edit your answer.

Comment: @kingmilo There's no `/bin/sh` reference in my answer

Comment: @kol there was before edit. Please also note $SHELL is the default shell for the system (or user), which is usually (but not necessarily) the shell that is actually being used at any given moment.

Comment: @kingmilo Please note that the question is "when i open terminal which shell is opened by default???" and that the answer is "If you didn't change any configuration it should be `Bash`, because that's the default shell on Ubuntu", so the answer fits the question

Comment: @kingmilo Reading the answer again i think i understand what is your concern, probably i didn't express myself well. I clarified the meaning of "currently" in my answer

Comment: The answer to use `ps -p "$$"` works in bash and possibly other shells but this will not work with fish ([Friendly Interactive SHell](https://fishshell.com/)). In fish you should run `ps -p %self`. So I am not sure there is any one command that you can run to tell you what shell you are in. You may need to try both of these and possibly other commands to determine that.

Comment: @frederickjh fish is a bit of an odd one out here. The `$$` variable is actually [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_02) and will work on the vast majority of shells. Fish has decided not to follow the standard here so I think it's fair to ignore it. I can confirm that `$$` works as expected in sh, dash, bash, zsh, ksh, ash, tcsh and csh. In fact, off the top of my head I can't think of any other shell except fish where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You may not want to know the *current shell's name* (e.g. `-bash`, `bash`, `zsh`, etc., from `echo $0`), nor *default shell's executable path* (from `echo $SHELL`), but rather the **current shell's executable path** (especially useful e.g. if you have more than one version of Bash installed).

To do this you can use `lsof -p "$$"` or with some extra coding to extract just the required info:

```
lsof -p "$$" | grep -m 1 txt | xargs -n 1 | tail -n 1
```

Example output for Bash installed via Homebrew:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/bash/5.1.8/bin/bash
```

or for Zsh:

```
/bin/zsh
```

The above is different from `echo $SHELL`, both because the above is for the shell which is currently running rather than the user's default shell, and also because the above gives the executable after any symlinks have been expanded. E.g. for the same Bash install as above, `echo $SHELL` gives `/usr/local/bin/bash`.

**EDIT 1:** If you need to allow for possible space characters in the shell's path, use `lsof -p "$$" | grep -m 1 txt | xargs -n 1 | tail -n +9 | xargs` instead.

**EDIT 2:** Yet another way to see the current shell's executable, this time not using `lsof`, is `ls -l "/proc/$$/exe"`.

Converting this to a command which doesn't require `lsof`, allows for possible spaces in the shell executable path and allows for possible aliases of `ls`, we get:

```
"$(which ls)" -l "/proc/$$/exe" | xargs -n 1 | tail -n +11 | xargs
```

Note that this last version with `/proc/$$` does not work on macOS, whereas the versions with `lsof` do, as well as on any Linux with `lsof` installed.

Answer (score 4):

To address your third question, "How do I change the shell used from my account?", the answer is to use `chsh`.

There are two modes:

- interactive, and;
- non-interactive.

From [Changing Shells](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ChangingShells) - [Changing your login shell which is permanent](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ChangingShells#Changing_your_login_shell_which_is_permanent), and paraphrasing it slightly:

> You will use a program called **chsh**. There is a interactive method
> and non-interactive method. Type the following into your terminal:
>
> #### INTERACTIVE METHOD
>
> ```
> $ chsh
> ```
>
> This results in a brief dialog in which the user is prompted first for
> their password and then for the full path of the desired new shell.
>
> Caution should be exercised when changing one's default shell because
> it is possible to make an error that only the root user (i.e., system
> administrator) can repair (although it should be easy for a skilled
> user to repair it on a home system). In particular, it is important to
> first test the shell temporarily in the current session and then to
> make certain that a valid shell name is being entered when making the
> permanent change.
>
> #### NON-INTERACTIVE METHOD
>
> I will use csh as again an example.
>
> ```
> $ chsh -s /bin/csh
> ```
>
> The `-s` sets it for you without having to go into the editor to do
> it.
>
> Once this is executed successfully, then `echo $SHELL` will still say
> that you are in the same shell as before. However, you need to log out
> and back in for the change to take effect. Now do `echo $SHELL`. You
> should see it shows the new shell.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the servers I connect to, the login shell is `/bin/sh` which is a symlink to `/bin/bash`

Most answers here will give `sh`, which would make the OP consider it's Bourne shell and not GNU bash, except [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1022440/156751) that gives `/bin/bash`

Another option that works for this case is:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh

$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 May 31 16:15 /bin/sh -> bash

$ /bin/sh --help
GNU bash, version 4.2.10(1)
Usage:  /bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] ...
        /bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
```

Comment: Possibly the answer I've just added also addresses this issue? I'm not quite sure how cross-system it is, so would be interested to know how it works for you on that server. :)