# How do I check which terminal I am using?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I have Ubuntu on my machine and I am running awesome window manager on top of it. How do I check which terminal I am running? Is there a command for it?

Comment: what do you mean by *which*? Click *Help* --> *About* is that it?

Comment: __Which terminal__ meaning the terminal program or the shell ?

Comment: you can see if you are using bash or zsh by doing `ps` usually it works and there are only a few processes.

Answer (score 68):

#### TL;DR

- to find currently running shell use `ls -l /proc/$$/exe`
- to find currently running terminal, use `xprop _NET_WM_PID WM_CLASS`. The value of `pid` later can be passed to `ps -p <pid> -o args` command.
- Technically, for terminal emulator you don't even need a command, as stated in the [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640096/how-do-i-check-which-terminal-i-am-using/640105#comment915482_640096):

  > what do you mean by which? Click Help --> About is that it? – [JoKeR](https://askubuntu.com/users/235295/joker)

#### Shell vs Terminal

First thing we need to have clarified is what exactly is being asked - find out the running shell or running terminal. Often these two terms are used interchangeably, but they are different things altogether. Shell is the command-line interpreter, specifically interactive shell is the prompt plus text field where you enter commands. Shells can also be non-interactive, for example a script starts non-interactive shell, or `bash -c 'echo hello world'` also starts non-interactive shell.

By contrast, terminal is the interface to shell ( though it could be another application as well). Originally terminal referred to actual hardware, but nowadays they're mostly software. What you see when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> or click on the terminal icon in GUI, that starts a terminal emulator, a window which mimics behavior of hardware, and within that window you can see the shell running. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (or any of the 6 function keys) will open virtual console, aka `tty`. I recommend reading [Why is a virtual terminal “virtual”, and what/why/where is the “real” terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/14284/295286) for more info on the specifics.

#### Getting the shell information

Each user has a default shell assigned to them in `/etc/passwd` for their username. Assuming you are using default configuration and haven't called another shell explicitly as a command, it is sufficient to do:

```
echo $SHELL
```

But of course this only shows *default* value. Suppose we do the following:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ dash
$
```

We were originally in `bash`, but started interactive session of `/bin/dash`, [Ubuntu's POSIX or system shell](https://askubuntu.com/q/976485/295286). The variable `$SHELL` won't change,  because that's not its purpose - it shows default not current value. We will need to approach this from another perspective - the perspective of a process, which is something I've covered in Am I using bash or sh?

```
$ echo $$
4824
$ cat /proc/4824/comm                                                          
mksh
$ bash
xieerqi@eagle:~$ echo $$
6197
xieerqi@eagle:~$ cat /proc/6197/comm
bash
```

Here we take advantage of `/proc/` filesystem. The name of the process and command-line parameters are displayed in `/proc/<pid>/comm`. All we need is to provide shell's PID, which is what `$$` does. In the example above I am adding that separately, but there is nothing stopping us from doing just

```
cat /proc/$$/comm
```

Variation on the theme could also be

```
ps -p $$ -o args
```

Another way we could approach this is via checking where `/proc/<pid>/exe`. This file is a symlink that points to the executable file. Thus we can do

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /proc/$$/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 adminx adminx 0 Apr  4 18:20 /proc/1241/exe -> /bin/bash
user@ubuntu:~$ sh
$ ls -l /proc/$$/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 adminx adminx 0 Apr  4 18:20 /proc/1255/exe -> /bin/dash
```

Either of the two approaches works in 99% of the cases. Of course, there are ways in which they can be subverted. For instance, symlink won't point anywhere if the executable was deleted shortly after the shell started ( and in that case you probably will encounter system issues, since removing `/bin/sh`, `/bin/dash`, or even `/bin/bash` is not recommended - after all a lot of scripts rely on them, especially system-level ones). Command name for shell is usually set as the very first argument in `execve()` syscall. This is covered in [How does bash know how it is being invoked?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78000/85039) , so if you have an application that launches a shell via `execve()`, it could give it any name. But these are non-standard and non-typical things, that should be avoided for the sake of consistency and security.

---

#### Getting Terminal Information

We can start with the environment variables. Many terminals seem to mask themselves as `xterm`-compatible, which is reported by `echo $TERM` or `echo $COLORTERM`. But then environment variables are not very reliable tool. They can be set and unset. We can do the same thing with PIDs again, except this time we will look at parent PID. As you may remember, terminal is the interface to the shell and often starts the shell itself. Therefore we can find out what process is the parent process of our shell:

```
$ ps -p $$ -o args,ppid
COMMAND                      PPID
bash                         1234
$ ps -p 1234 -o args
COMMAND
/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
```

Let's try with another terminal app, `sakura`:

```
$ ps -p $$ -o args,ppid
COMMAND                      PPID
/bin/bash                   16950
$ ps -p 16950 -o args
COMMAND
sakura
```

From there we can already see that what started this shell is `gnome-terminal`. This method of course works assuming you're working with interactive shell. If we're trying to find out the parent of `bash -c '...'` or the shell started via `ssh`, for example, PID may very well be from non-terminal application and maybe non-GUI at all.

So if we want to specifically deal with GUI terminal, what we can do is run `xprop`, click on the desired window, grep its pid, and find out what's the name of that process matching pid. Or in other words:

```
$ ps aux | grep $(xprop | awk -F'='  '/PID/ {print $2}')                       
xieerqi   2124  0.6  1.7 208068 34604 ?        Sl   18:47   1:49 gnome-terminal
```

Additionally, as [per specifications](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#WM_CLASS) , window managers should set `WM_CLASS` property. Thus, we can get that from `xprop` as well:

```
$ xprop WM_CLASS 
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "sakura", "Sakura"
```

Of course, this also has its 1% of disadvantages: setting `WM_CLASS` properties relies on window manager doing that, and PID is not guaranteed for a window to be accurate ( see [What process created this X11 window?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/what-process-created-this-x11-window) ), which may involve complex debugging. And these aren't shortcomings of the methods themselves but of X11 server. However, most stable and well known window managers ( like openbox, Metacity, blackbox ) and most applications are well behaved so we shouldn't expect problems with something like Gnome Terminal or Terminator.

But when it comes to GUI terminal emulators, we don't even need to find a command. We can just use the `About` dialog of the window itself. Exception to that rule is `xterm`.

Comment: O_o `$SHELL`, sure

Comment: Eek. Why do you people use `ps | grep`? `ps -p $$`! Or, just for the command, `ps -p $$ -o cmd=`.

Comment: NOTE: I've updated my answer, since this question overall was originally unclear, and parts of it require some background; over time I also figured out there's better ways to invoke commands.

Comment: WARNING: do not use  xprop _NET_WM_PID WM_CLASS as your system will lock up and freeze!

Comment: When I try `ps -p $$ -o args,ppid` in Git Bash, I get `ps: unknown option -- o`

Answer (score 22):

If you want to know the terminal program you are using, use this:

```
ps -o 'cmd=' -p $(ps -o 'ppid=' -p $$)
```

Run this just after opening the terminal (shell) *without forking any further shell instance*.

When you open up the terminal program, it basically spawns a child program, a shell. So the parent of the spawned shell is the terminal itself. In other words, the PPID of the shell is the PID of terminal program.

Here we are finding the parent process ID (PPID) of the shell (`bash`) by `ps -o 'ppid=' -p $$` , which will be the process ID of terminal program.

Then we are finding the process name from the PID:

```
$ ps -o 'cmd=' -p $(ps -o 'ppid=' -p $$)
gnome-terminal
```

It is basically a one liner of:

```
$ ps -o 'ppid=' -p $$
 2268

$ ps -o 'cmd=' -p 2268
gnome-terminal
```

Comment: When I run this command I get `sshd: username@pts/4`.  Note I'm using PuTTY to connect to the machine.  Is `sshd` actually the terminal emulator?

Comment: @user3731622, did you find an answer to this question? Did you ask it elsewhere?

Answer (score 17):

The short version (thx [@Serg](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/serg))

```
cat /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator
```

---

The long version

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

and look for the `*` in the output

**;)**

---

*Example output*

```
There are 7 alternatives which provide `x-terminal-emulator’.
```

```
Selection Alternative
———————————————–
    1 /usr/bin/xterm
    2 /usr/bin/uxterm
    3 /usr/bin/koi8rxterm
    4 /usr/bin/lxterm
 *+ 5 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
    6 /usr/bin/konsole
    7 /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper
```

```
Press enter to keep the default[*], or type selection number:
```

---

Or, thanks to [@muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru), here is more detailed output

```
$ update-alternatives --display x-terminal-emulator
x-terminal-emulator - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper - priority 40
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/gnome-terminal.1.gz
/usr/bin/koi8rxterm - priority 20
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/koi8rxterm.1.gz
/usr/bin/lxterm - priority 30
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/lxterm.1.gz
/usr/bin/mate-terminal.wrapper - priority 30
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/mate-terminal.1.gz
/usr/bin/uxterm - priority 20
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/uxterm.1.gz
/usr/bin/xterm - priority 20
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/xterm.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper'.
```

Comment: `cat /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator | grep exec`

Comment: Is there a utility I need installed?  I get either `Binary file (standard input) matches` or `update-alternatives: error: unknown argument `–config'`

Comment: Nevermind, it is `--config`

Comment: You don't need `sudo`. Use `update-alternatives --display x-terminal-emulator`

Comment: For the short version you might consider using `file /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator` to get the target of this symbolic link instead using `cat` on it. The `file` utility should be installed on most systems and can be used to find the target executable. `cat` on symbolic link could print any shell script or even binary file depending on the target of this link (shell script for `gnome-terminal`, binary file `urxvt`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, this solved my mouse scrolling problem when logging through SSH using MobaXTerm. The default GNOME-Terminal interpreted mouse scroll as up / down arrow in VIM.

Answer (score 5):

Use `tty` - prints the file name of the terminal connected to standard input.

In `gnome-terminal`:

```
 $ tty
 /dev/pts/2
```

In a virtual terminal (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>):

```
 $ tty
 /dev/tty4
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the name of the terminal program, you'll most probably find it under Help > About.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to install neofectch

```
sudo apt install neofetch
```

Just type the below given command and checkout the terminal

```
neofetch
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator | grep exec
```

Sample output:

> exec('gnome-terminal',@args);

There's the answer for my system: **gnome-terminal**.

So, typing `gnome-terminal` into my terminal will now open up another identical terminal window.

#### Sources:

- Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy's comment under [A.B.'s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/640104/327339).

Answer (score 0):

Run `neofetch` and it will tell you.

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1371032/

Answer (score 0):

When it is run in an interactive shell, the [solution proposed by heemayl](https://askubuntu.com/a/640112/1570285) `ps -o 'cmd=' -p $(ps -o 'ppid=' -p $$)` accurately retrieves the terminal program, which is the parent of the shell. Within a script, however, the immediate parent is the invoking shell, not the terminal. Consequently, this command yields the shell name — Bash, in my case — when executed within a script.
To address this, one could traverse up the process tree from the script, examining the parent of each shell process until encountering a non-shell process. This non-shell process is then presumed to be the terminal program.

Bash:

```bash
pid=$$
while true; do
    cmd=$(ps -o 'cmd=' -p $pid | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
    if [[ "$cmd" != "bash" ]]; then
        terminal=$cmd
        break
    fi
    pid=$(ps -o 'ppid=' -p $pid)
done
echo $terminal
```

Other shells:

```sh
pid=$$
while true; do
    cmd=$(ps -o 'cmd=' -p $pid | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
    case "$cmd" in
        bash|sh|csh|ksh|zsh|fish) ;;
        *) terminal=$cmd; break ;;
    esac
    pid=$(ps -o 'ppid=' -p $pid)
done
echo $terminal
```

Answer (score -1):

**Simple answer.  Works for both console or ssh.**

Example for simple character terminal:

```
ssh username@systemname
echo $TERM
dumb
```

tells you that you can't open GUI apps on that connection

Example for xterm  (also works with PuTTY/Xming on Windows)

```
ssh -Y username@systemname      -- omit this if using PuTTY --
echo $TERM
xterm
```

means that you can use GUI commands like opening the leafpad editor or nautilus file manager.

On the console it is the same:

```
Open terminal window
echo $TERM
xterm
```

Comment: `TERM` is not a variable that defines the default terminal emulator, but rather one that defines the capabilities of the current one. For example, setting the variable to "xterm-color" lets any program running in the terminal know that the current terminal is supposed to understand colours; setting it to "linux" tells programs that this is supposed to be a VT; etc.