# Can't change shell from zsh to bash?

Tags: bash, 20.04, zsh

I've just installed zsh on Ubuntu 20.04 and decided to change it back to bash. I tried common way which is `chsh` but it doesn't work.

Reference:
[changing shell from zsh to bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385672/changing-shell-from-zsh-to-bash)

Current shell

```
wolf@linux:/home/wolf $ echo $SHELL 
/bin/zsh
wolf@linux:/home/wolf $
```

1st attempt

```
wolf@linux:/home/wolf $ sudo chsh -s /bin/bash
wolf@linux:/home/wolf $ echo $SHELL           
/bin/zsh
wolf@linux:/home/wolf $
```

2nd attempt

```
wolf@linux:~$ sudo chsh --shell=/bin/bash $USER
wolf@linux:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
wolf@linux:~$
```

3rd attempt

```
wolf@linux:~$ chsh -s $(which bash)
Password: 
wolf@linux:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
wolf@linux:~$
```

Even bash and exec bash do not work

```
wolf@linux:/home/wolf $ bash
wolf@linux:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
wolf@linux:~$ exec bash
wolf@linux:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
wolf@linux:~$
```

Comment: It doesn't change until you reboot.  `chsh` changes your default shell in the `/etc/passwd` file.  You can always just run `/bin/bash` to go back to `bash` for now.

Comment: You could always use `exec bash` to replace the current shell with the command, in this case, the desired shell. It will destroy the previous shell process, thou.

Answer (score 4):

`chsh` changes the shell field in the password database, which is read on login. To see the effect of the change, you need to start a new *login session* - for example with `su -`:

Ex. confirm current login shell is bash:

```
steeldriver@DESKTOP:~$ getent passwd steeldriver
steeldriver:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/steeldriver:/bin/bash
steeldriver@DESKTOP:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Change the shell - the password database is updated immediately but the value of `$SHELL` doesn't change

```
steeldriver@DESKTOP:~$ chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
Password:

steeldriver@DESKTOP:~$ getent passwd steeldriver
steeldriver:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/steeldriver:/usr/bin/zsh
steeldriver@DESKTOP:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Now start a new login session:

```
steeldriver@DESKTOP:~$ su - steeldriver
Password:
steeldriver@DESKTOP-SPDO14V ~ % echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/zsh
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `chsh -s /bin/bash` (enter password when prompted)
2. Log out
3. Log back in
4. `echo $SHELL` to confirm